# empty space in long string for eg. append function

Tags: jquery, html, string, editor

I have a very basic question about the strings inside (or elsewhere) an `.append()` function. Sometimes I have a long codesnippet, like this

```
c = '<div id="slider"><ul style="position: absolute; top: -400px"><li><img src="img/link/eins.png"></li><li><img src="img/link/zwei.png"></li><li><img src="img/link/drei.png"></li><li><img src="img/link/vier.png"></li><li><img src="img/link/fuenf.png"></li><li><img id="linkimg6" class="val4" style="display: none;" src="img/link/sechs.png"></li><li><img id="linkimg7" class="val4" style="display: none;" src="img/link/sieben.png"><img src="img/link/acht.png"></li><li><img src="img/link/neun.png"></li></ul></div>',
```

as I know its very important that there is no space between, means when I try to make a linebreak in my Text-Editor it throws me an error. My Question is, is there another way to write this string that I dont have such a long line in my editor. Its very confusing.

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always consider splitting it into multiple strings and concatenating them:

```
var html = '<div>First row:'+
               '<span>info</span>'+
           '</div>'+
           '<div>Done</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to vary slightly towards the end.  Based on your design, i was thinking you wanted it to look the same across the board.

What i do in jquery is have a list of URLs, and then since the list is ordered, iterate over it.  For each iteration, i create a new img and assign the src, add that new image to a new List Item, and then append that new list item to the unordered list.
//jquery:

```
var $slide = $("<div id='slider' />"),
    $ul = $("<ul class='ul_css' />").css({position:"absolute", top:"-400px"}),
    $li = $("<li />"),
    $img = $("<img />");
var list = ["img/link/eins.png","img/link/eins.png","img/link/drei.png","img/link/vier.png","img/link/fuenf.png","img/link/sechs.png","img/link/sieben.png","img/link/acht.png","img/link/neun.png"];

$slide.append($ul);
for (var item in list){
    $ul.append($li.clone().append($img.clone().attr("src", list[item])));
}
```

granted, this does not account for your cases of random img tags given IDs and classes.

if your point was to break it into more lines, you could just do:

```
url = part1;
url += part2;
url + part3; //etc or

url = part1 +
      part2 +
      part3;
```